# IntelliJ indicating that enhanced switch block doesn't work despite using Java 14

Tags: java, intellij-idea, switch-statement

I am trying to use the enhanced switch block that was standardized in Java 14. The old version is this:

```java
switch (expression) {
    case OPTION1:
        foo();
        break;
    case OPTION2:
        bar();
        break;
}
```

however since I am using Java 14, I should be able to use this:

```java
switch (expression) {
    case OPTION1 -> foo();
    case OPTION2 -> bar();
}
```

Here is a MRE:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String demo = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "Hello": "World";
        switch (demo) {
            case "Hello" -> System.out.println("The string contained Hello");
            case "World" -> System.out.println("The string contained World");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The code in my IDE]

When I write that code, IntelliJ gives me the following warning:

[image: Enhanced 'switch' blocks are not supported at language level '14']

> Enhanced 'switch' blocks are not supported at language level '14'

However, that warning, despite being highlighted in red to indicate a compile time error, is incorrect. The code compiles correctly and the switch block works as intended because I am using Java 14. Why am I getting this warning?

Edit: Project structure per request

[image: Project structure]

Edit: My iml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="module-library">
      <library>
        <CLASSES>
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/Downloads/MathParser.org-mXparser-v.4.4.0/MathParser.org-mXparser-v.4.4.0/bin/jdk13/MathParser.org-mXparser-v.4.4.0-jdk13.jar!/" />
        </CLASSES>
        <JAVADOC />
        <SOURCES />
      </library>
    </orderEntry>
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: Is this your whole code ?

Comment: @YusofKhan Yes. That's enough to generate the error message, however it compiles just fine.

Comment: I have tried it and is working fine with me

Comment: @YusofKhan Just to compare settings, my project SDK is Java 14.0.1 and my project language level is SDK default.

Comment: Invalidate caches and restart perhaps?

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke I've encountered this issue in multiple projects and have restarted since first encountering it. How do I invalidate a cache?

Comment: File > Invalidate Caches and Restart

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke I'm still seeing the error.

Comment: Feel free to upvote or accept any answers that are useful

Comment: @Andrew The issue hasn't been resolved at this point, so I can't accept any as of yet, however I appreciate the effort on the part of everyone who has tried to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use intellij 2020

Normally the reason for this is the sdk, jdk and language level are not aligned,

Check in the project structure project tab that  Project and Modules are consistent see below (ok I am using language level 11)

[image]
[image]

Project showing openjdk-14
[image]

ide inserted java14.iml file contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_14" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/com" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: There are two: 1) 14  uses switch expressions and 2) 14(preview) records, patterns and  text blocks, are you using the 2nd?

Comment: Just tried this myself and language level 14 switch expressions works fine with your code , the ide prompts this as a fix as my default path uses java 11. Your suggestion prompt suggests checking the module settings though... most strange

Comment: I don't see either. Non of the options in the drop down menu have a 14. The one I had by default just said `SDK default (X - Experimental features)`

Comment: So under the external libraries in the project structure can you see the libraries for  openjdk 14 ?

Comment: Sorry, where would I check that?

Comment: In the main area of the ide left hand pane, the project pane where the src packages and code is, lower down there is an external libraries section expand that

Comment: I'm seeing Java 14.

Comment: also added my iml file to check. It shows the JDK-14 there

Comment: I'm not sure how to read the iml file, so I'll add it to the question. Mine is a bit longer because I have downloaded an additional external library for use in this project.

Comment: double click it in the ide to open it, you can see it in the project pane

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm able to view it, I just don't understand what it says.

Comment: see my answer I posted mine which is simple consle project doe it have component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_14" inherit-compiler-output="true"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219632/discussion-between-a-p-and-andrew).

Comment: I finally got around to updating. It solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it is working just fine I think you might forget to add the package name

```
package com.company;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String demo = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "Hello": "World";
        switch (demo)
        {
            case "Hello" -> System.out.println("The string contained Hello");
            case "World" -> System.out.println("The string contained World");
        }
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot for my project structure is try to compare it with yours

[image]

Comment: That's not the issue. I had a package name in my real program where I encountered the error, I just put the MRE in a default package because it is only for demo purposes.

Comment: can you add a screenshot for your project structure

Comment: I can add a screenshot but the only thing in the project is Main.java. I don't think it is going to help.

Comment: @ap I have added a screenshot for what I need

Comment: Try to create a new project and rewrite the code or copy and paste the code not sure if it will helps

Comment: I've encountered this issue in multiple projects. I created a new project and added this code for the purpose of making the MRE. I noticed that in parenthesis by your project language level, it says "14 - switch expressions". In the drop down menu, I have "13 - switch expressions", but not 14. Is that part of the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219630/discussion-between-yusof-khan-and-a-p).